# Comparing two strings in c++ in ROS

Tags: c++, ros

I am trying to compare two strings in the following method on ROS

```
std::string line_eval_str = std::string(line_eval)+"";
std::string check ("checking condition");

while(/*some condtion*/)
{
     if(check.compare(line_eval_str) == 1)
    {   
         ROS_ERROR("Breaking the loop!!!!! %s",line_eval);
         break;
    }
    else
   {  
        /*execute this part*/
   }
}
```

Here even though `line_eval_str` and `check` have the same string in them `else` part is executed. 
I also tried other method

```
while(/*some condtion*/)
{
    if(strcmp(line_eval_str,check) == 1)
    {   
        ROS_ERROR("Breaking the loop!!!!! %s",line_eval);
        break;
    }
    else
    {  
     /*execute this part*/
    }
}
```

Even this code provides the same result ( ie,. the strings have same value `else` part is executed).
I don't understand what is the problem. Does it have to do something with ROS?

Answer (score 2):

> Here even though line_eval_str and check have the same string in them else part is executed

This is the expected behaviour: both [`string::compare()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare) and [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp) return `0` (and not `1`) if the strings are equal. If you want the `if()` body to execute, you need to test the return value against `0`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string str1 = "Hello";
  std::string str2 = "Hello";

  if (str1.compare(str2) == 0) {
    std::cerr << "Strings are equal" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Strings are NOT equal" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ -o cmp cmp.c
$ ./cmp
Strings are equal
```

For better readability, you should use the [comparison operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/operators/) instead of the compare method:

```
if (str1 == str2) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried **if (str1 == str2)** but for some reason this didn't work as expected.

Comment: It is still working the same way as before. I replaced the code snippet with    **if(line_eval_str == check)**   , where both are strings

Comment: @ADI perhaps your strings are not the same then.